# Inspecting contents from SFSafariViewController on iPhone

Tags: cordova, safari, web-inspector, sfsafariviewcontroller

We have an Ionic app and are trying to make use of "embedded Safari" version for displaying web contents - [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller).

We use [cordova-plugin-browsertab](https://github.com/google/cordova-plugin-browsertab) plugin.

The problem is - **how to debug/inspect anything from inside that embedded Safari** ? In Safari, normal inspection just inspects the "root" app contents, but i cannot see anywhere any reference to the document opened with embedded safari.

Comment: did you find anything?